# 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=13.0.0.0', The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, sql-server, reference

I'm working on already developed desktop App which requires Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum reference, but now I'm getting an exception

```
'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I updated NuGet packages but still getting the same exception

Comment: Did you fully compile after updating?  Often the compiler dependencies do not recognize configuration changes.  So I normally recommend doing a full build.   To make sure every thing gets compiled I tell people to copy and delete the bin folder in the project and then compile.

Comment: after lots of searches, I found the desired suggestion as I did not installed the SQL Shared Management Objects. [link](https://support.timextender.com/hc/en-us/articles/210437663-Error-Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-Microsoft-SqlServer-ConnectionInfo-)   . I installed Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects -Version 140.17283.0 and it solved my issue.